# Laravel, Many-to-many relationships, find() vs where()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I have a Laravel 4.2 site with a pretty simple database layout. The important part is a `People` model and a `Subject` model that have a many-to-many relationship. This works, so that, for instance:

```
$id = 5;
$ppl = Subject::find($id)->people()->orderBy('lastname')->get();
```

Returns all `People` for a given `Subject`. What I'm trying to do is instead of finding all the `People` for a **single** subject, to find all the people for **multiple** subjects. My guess was something like this:

```
$subjects = array(5, 6, 7);
$ppl = Subject::whereIn('id', $subjects)->people()->orderBy('lastname')->get();
```

That doesn't work (undefined method people()). Neither does the following (undefined property people):

```
$ppl = Subject::whereIn('id', $subjects)->people->orderBy('lastname')->get();
```

I'm currently just using raw SQL t get around this. How can I use eloquent relationships with `where()` or `whereIn()` calls on a model? Or, is there just a better eloquent way of approaching this problem.

Edit: Here's the raw SQL I used to get a list of the people.id's for a given array of subjects:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(people.id) 
  FROM people 
  LEFT JOIN person_subject ON person_subject.person_id=people.id 
  WHERE 
    person_subject.subject_id IN (%s) AND 
    deleted_at IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your eloquent relationships should allow you to eagar load the people related to a subject, you can do something like this:

```
Subject::whereIn('id', $subjects)->with('people')->orderBy('lastname')->get();
```

This will return your people related to the subjects.

Let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: That line returns `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lastname' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from ``subjects`` where ``id`` in (141, 164, 100) order by ``last name`` asc)`

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to join the tables to order by the lastname:

```
$ppl = Subject::whereIn('id', $subjects)
    ->select('subjects.*')
    ->distinct()
    ->join('people', 'people.id', '=', 'subjects.people_id')
    ->orderBy('lastname')
     ->get();
```

Check all your tables names because I don't know them and above are just an example one.